# Azure Container Instances unable to pull public docker hub images with docker compose deployment

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

I'm trying to deploy a docker compose file to Azure Container Instances (ACI) using public Dockerhub images with these two tutorials, [docker](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/), [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrCDT5Ezmcc). However, it keeps saying I can't pull a public dockerhub image

```
containerinstance.ContainerGroupsClient#CreateOrUpdate: 
  Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="MultipleErrorsOccurred" 
  Message="Multiple error occurred: 
    'BadRequest':'InaccessibleImage':'The image 'selenium/standalone-firefox:latest' in container group 'test_ui_automation' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential.
```

The process itself should be when an ACI instance gets setup so there's no register details existing and the image is public on docker hub.

I've logged into Azure and Docker Hub. Based on the youtube tutorial, it should just be a process of creating an ACI instance, then running `docker compose -f azure-testproject-docker.yaml -d`.

azure-testproject-docker.yaml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  testproject-agent:
    image: testproject/agent:latest
    container_name: testproject-agent
    depends_on:
      - chrome
      - firefox
    volumes:
      - mydata:/var/testproject/agent
    environment:
      TP_AGENT_ALIAS: "MY DOCKER AGENT"
      TP_API_KEY: "MY KEY"
      TP_JOB_PARAMS: '"jobParameters" : { "browsers": [ "chrome", "firefox" ] }'
      CHROME: "chrome:4444"
      FIREFOX: "firefox:4444"
  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    volumes:
      - mydata:/dev/shm
  firefox:
    image: selenium/standalone-firefox:latest
    volumes:
      - mydata:/dev/shm

volumes:
  mydata:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: myfileshare
      storage_account_name: mystorageaccount
```

The docker-compose file is quite basic, just used TestProject's default docker compose file. The images download on local docker, but the azure part doesn't work.

The whole point was to deploy with only a Docker Compose file, no Dockerfile as it's just using public dockerhub images.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

**Solution**

Remove container_name as not supported in ACI

Comment: First you should look at supported ACI docker-compose features, as at least container_name is not supported.
https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-compose-features/

Comment: Please also execute command "docker context ls" to be sure that you have ACI context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was simply due to container_name not being supported.

As per comment by andriy-bilous

```
First you should look at supported ACI docker-compose features, as at least container_name is not supported. docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-compose-features – Andriy Bilous 17 hours ago
```

Resolved the issue just by removing the container_name line.